# Shrinkage Estimator giving unrealistic portfolio variances

Tags: finance, portfolio-optimization

I have a historical covariance matrix which is invertible for daily and monthly returns. I used the Ledoit,Wolf shrinkage estimator for the covariance matrix and now I get really small portfolio variances, implying unrealistic Sharpe-ratios. I assume this has to do with the fact that I didn't shrink the return vector. Which shrinkage estimator would you use on the return vector? Do you know any R-Script for this?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because asking for code does not constitute a proper question

Comment: Come down! I wasn't asking for a code. I'm primarily asking if anyone has had similar problems of having a covariance matrix constituting of too small values after using the Ledoit-Wolf shrinkage estimator and knows what could be the problem or how one could solve this.

Comment: It is not clear that this is the use of the Ledoit-Wolf shrinkage. (Indeed, it is not clear L-W shrinkage has _any_ use.)